# How to generate types.json in substrate

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

In polkadot-js has provided for developer to define custom types in the pallet, so that polkadot-ui can understand those types (it means can use some underlying API polkadot-js). These types are defined using the json format. This is example

```
{
  "TransactionInput": {
    "parent_output": "Hash",
    "signature": "Signature"
  },
  "TransactionOutput": {
    "value": "u128",
    "pubkey": "Hash",
    "sale": "u32"
  },
  "Transaction": {
    "inputs": "Vec<TransactionInput>",
    "outputs": "Vec<TransactionOutput>"
  }
}
```

I see that in **substrate-node-template/scripts** has **aggregrate_types.js** file that generate types.json. I dont know how to generate it automaticly or I should write by hand.
Example that, in my pallet that i have defined ***enum RoleID*** and ***struct Role***. But in UI it doesn't understand what RoleID is. Can you explain more clearly? I believe that it can be related to define types.json.
[image]
https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/page-settings/src/md/basics.md#developer

aggregrate_types.json:
[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't see the `aggregrate_types.js` you mention [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node-template/scripts) - can you point that out?

Comment: Thanks for reply!!! aggregrate_types.js that i mention in susbtrate-node-template. Yeah when i check in github they delete this file. But in some previous commit, they have

Comment: @NukeManDan The aggregate_type.js script can be found here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/recipes/search?q=filename%3Aaggregate_types.js

Answer (score 1):

Presently, generating this by hand is the best way following the docs [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend). There are not clean ways to automatically generate this to my knowlage, but soon you will not need to worry about at all it once [this PR lands](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8615) in Substrate!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8615, you don't have to manually write `types.json` anymore.

Make sure the metadata version of your node is v14 or higher. Otherwise you need to upgrade your substrate version to make it automagically work for you.